# jQuery function not found in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

i have some code in simple html and it works fine but when i put in wordpress it does not work. its simple jquery slider which i am putting by hardcode in index.php

here is how i am adding script

```
<script src="<?php echo PARENT_URL; ?>/js/bjqs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

here is html which i am putting in index.php file after body tag

```
<div class="bjqs-slider">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li><img src="urlofimage.jpg" alt=""></li> 
        <li><img src="urlofimage.jpg" alt=""></li> 
        <li><img src="urlofimage.jpg" alt=""></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is jquery where i am calling slider function

```
$(".bjqs-slider").bjqs({
    animtype      : 'slide',
    height        : 250,
    width         : 300,
    responsive    : true,
    randomstart   : true
});
```

so when i check using firebug, it show `bjqs is not a function` but bjqs.js file is also loading fine. and the same code works fine in local html file

Comment: 1.) Does your library loads properly? 2.) Have you put this slider code before your library? you have to check the network tab if library is loaded.

Comment: Yes it is loading properly. when i press ctrl + u and click on src it is showing the library code. also i checked network tab it is loading properly. another thing it is loading after jquery loaded.  i tried another library which is also working fine in local html page but in wordpress giving same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. the problem was in the library code. library code was like this in the start

`;(function($) {`

and now i changed to

`$(function($) {`

and it worked fine.

Comment: Just so you know with the first version of the code the DOM is not yet loaded, while with the second one the code is executed after the DOM is loaded. More info -- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to work

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

```
// here your code


});
```

Answer (score 0):

the way of the bjqs.file is Correct? Mybe the src is Wrong.you can log the src of bjqs.file to contain it's correct.